# restful webservice get list of objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

My rest webservice returns the following output:

```
    {
    "result": {
       "TICKET1": {
            "number": "TICKET1",
            "description": "aa"
        },
        "TICKET2": {
            "number": "TICKET2",
            "description": "dd"
        }
     }
    }
```

To convert this into a list of Tickets I tried as below.

```
class TicketResponse {
     private List<Ticket> result;
     // Get Set
}

class Ticket {
     private String number;
     private String description;
     // Get Set
}

TicketResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject(WEB_SERVICE_URL, TicketResponse.class);
```

But I get `response` as null. How to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide two ways to do with the JSON structure you have.

**Option 1:**

Modify your `TicketResponse` class like below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class TicketResponse {

  @JsonProperty("result")
  private Map<String, Ticket> ticketsMap = new HashMap<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setUnknownField(String name, Ticket value) {
    ticketsMap.put(name, value);
  }

  @JsonIgnore private List<Ticket> ticketsList;

  public List<Ticket> getTicketsList() {
    return ticketsMap.entrySet().stream().map(Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

then you can get your list of tickets from:

```
response.getTicketsList();
```

**Option 2:**

Read your response in to a `String`

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(WEB_SERVICE_URL, String.class);
```

and use below code to convert it to a `List<Ticket>`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(response);
JsonNode wantedJsonNode = jsonNode.get("result");
Map<String, Ticket> map =
        mapper.convertValue(wantedJsonNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Ticket>>() {});
List<Ticket> tickets =
        map.entrySet().stream().map(Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: setUnknownField method is required?

Comment: yes, that's required. It populates the map, `@JsonAnySetter` is used to define a two argument method (key,value) to populate unrecognized properties found in the JSON. In your case,  non-static keys are TICKET1, TICKET2 etc.  and values are mapped to `Ticket` object.

Answer (score 0):

The object you provided doesn't contain a list/array, which would be inside square brackets, like this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "tickets": [
      {
        "number": "TICKET1",
        "description": "aa"
      },
      {
        "number": "TICKET2",
        "description": "dd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Change your service if possible to return a list/array.  Otherwise what you have is an object with individual fields named TICKET1 and TICKET2, so you'll need a field for each.

Answer (score 0):

TicketResponse must have a structure that corresponds to response of the service.
You can change your TicketResponse class and add getTicketArray method:

```
public class TicketResponse {
    private Map<String,Ticket> result;
    // getter setter

    public List<Ticket> getTicketsAsArray(){
        return new ArrayList<Ticket>(result.values());
    }
}
```